# Do I need "has" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, grammar

> "There's a feeling that (has) never helped anyone: hate.

Do I need the has there? Why or why not?

I found the [version](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1855&bih=990&tbm=bks&ei=1DYDWr7YGo3s8AW7kpyACw&q=%22there%20is%20%20a%20feeling%20that%20has%20never%22&oq=%22there%20is%20%20a%20feeling%20that%20has%20never%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1489.2114.0.2198.4.3.0.0.0.0.112.212.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0.4Vchu0VR9Hc) with "has". However, I also see the [version](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1855&bih=990&tbm=bks&ei=2DYDWuOdA4iY8gW32LLwBg&q=%22there%20is%20%20a%20feeling%20that%20%20never%22&oq=%22there%20is%20%20a%20feeling%20that%20%20never%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...50579.50579.0.50653.1.1.0.0.0.0.58.58.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.uxU9NHMew9M) without "has".

Comment: My (NNS) guess - **with has**. It was so in the past and is now, at the moment of speaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you **need** to put "has" in there? No, because both sentences are correct. But like "Mv Log" said in the comment, if you place "has" in there, then it sounds stronger. It sounds like there's no dispute over it. It gives an impression that it's not the case in the past, nor is it the case today.

If you remove "has", then it talks more about the past. It could still be that today someone got helped. Why? Because "helped" is in the past tense.

*(Hate is helpful, though. Imagine if you're addicted to drugs for over 10 years now, and you see the ill effects that drugs has on you. You'll start to hate drugs because of it. And you can use that hate to finally give up on drugs once and for all. I know this is not what the question is about, but you know... just saying xD)*